# Making the checkbox non-editable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an application which loads the result in a table view, there are around 10 columns in the table view. Out of the 10 columns there are 2 columns which are check boxes, Currently the values in the Result set come as 0 and 1. The problem is the values for the check box are coming currently like if its 1 the check box is checked if its 0 the check box is unchecked, but according to my requirement i don't want the check box to be editable, currently the check box is getting editable.

I tried using Editable Binding for the Check box, but it did not work.

Not sure how to achieve this!!
Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it:

```
[checkbox setEnabled:NO];
```

It will be greyed out then, but that should be OK, since that indicates it is not changeable.

[image: Disabled checkbox]

Comment: HI thanks for the Reply!!.. I have dragged an dropped an Check Box Cell on my column and then i added an IBOutlet    @property (strong) IBOutlet NSButtonCell *activeEnabled; and in my windowDidLoad i set the out let value as setEnabled NO, But still i am able to edit the check box!!

Comment: When you have a nib/xib, you can disable it already in the properties of the nib. There is an `Enabled` checkbox somewhere.

Comment: yeah in the attributes section we have a check box Enabled, but still I am able to check and uncheck that box...:(

Comment: That's weird. I just tested it here in my current app. By unchecking the "Enabled" checkbox in the attributes section the checkbox then is disabled in my app. See image above.

Comment: Hey the issue got solved, for the column binding i had checked the check box..Conditionally sets enabled and Conditionally sets disabled. After unchecking those 2 check box, the check boxes are now non-editable.          Thanks for the Help ..   :):)